# Auto incremented column with string prefix

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I need an autoincremented column with prefix which exist in database. I found solutions for computed columns if both columns exist in database, but I don't want to add a new int column for other column. So I need to define an ID column like "SomeCode|00001" and should increment automatically

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SomeHeaderClass>()
                .Property(s => s.ID)
                .HasComputedColumnSql($"CONCAT(SomeCodeCode,'|', IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL");
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

IDK about other solutions but I'm not a fan of doing this kind of computed column.

We can specify 2 columns, one for prefix value and one for increment value in this case, with an unique index using the combination of those two.

**Benefit:**

- Simplicity and performance. (small char and number have better perf compare to big char).
- Easily to scale as needed (what if the prefix length can evolve ?)
- Not depending on Database engine (as far as i can remember, not every RMDBS out there having such computed column feature, any even if there is, I'm sure the performance cannot compete with 2 separate column solution)

Comment: I totally agree with you, it was about client side issue. Fortunately they gave up on this kind of solution

Comment: AFAIK, we can totally combine them on backend side before return it to client side, so what was the prob ?